# Is it acceptable to use "aria-describedby" on a container with multiple children?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have the following piece of markup:

```
<input aria-describedby="a b c">/* generic form control */

<p id="a">foo</p>
<p id="b">foo</p>
<p id="c">foo</p>
```

Would it be acceptable/functional with regards to assistive technologies, to replace it with the following?

```
<input aria-describedby="d">

<div id="d">
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be acceptable/functional with regards to assistive technologies, to replace it with the following?

It is both acceptable and functional. The accessible description for the button becomes "foo foo foo".

What you need to be aware of is that the description is a flat string, no structure is conveyed. Also that verbosity can be an issue as each time the control recieves focus the screen reader will announce the description.

Also in you example code the button needs an end tag and the `aria-describedby` is not referencing anything, as you have a `class` attribute, it needs to be an `id` attribute. http://codepen.io/stevef/pen/ojBmdV

Comment: thanks - I couldn't ask for a better-suited person to answer this! I've edited the markup after your correct remarks. The behaviour you're describing is exactly what I was hoping, as each <p> will convey different content from each other (e.g. one would have additional explanation about the field that is not provided by the label)